# changing url in osclass

Tags: php, url-rewriting, osclass

I want to change the url on osclass and replace the `,` with `-`
now url is like : `127.0.0.1/en/search/region,9354963/category,books-magazines` and I want to convert url to `127.0.0.1/en/search/region-9354963/category-books-magazines`

I did try to change the `init()` in `classes/Rewrite.php` and add the code :

```
$modified_params = array();
for ($p = 1; $p < count($route_match); $p++) {
    $param_value = str_replace(',', '-', $route_match[$p]);
    $modified_params[] = $param_value;
}

// Set the modified parameters to Params
for ($p = 0; $p < count($modified_params); $p++) {
    if (isset($args[1][$p])) {
        Params::setParam($args[1][$p], $modified_params[$p]);
    } else {
        Params::setParam('route_param_' . ($p + 1), $modified_params[$p]);
    }
}
```

but still no luck

Comment: Having never used or even looked at `osclass` judging from the above it looks like the final complete urls are generated after this code

Comment: Is this function get reached?

Comment: yes the function is getting reached

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace , with -, as it would not be possible to differentiate between - in slug and delimiter of param and value.

Example: /region-alabama/city-bremen

It is not possible to identify if this is category structure or search url structure.
As far as I know, comma is seo friendly char and there is no need for its change, but if you really want to do it, it will not be sufficient to change just this piece.
Still, you will need to use different char like dot as example.